# Mapping many Eithers to one Either with many

Tags: scala, monads

Say I have a monadic function in called `processOne` defined like this:

`def processOne(input: Input): Either[ErrorType, Output] = ...`

Given a list of "`Inputs`", I would like to return a corresponding list of "`Outputs`" wrapped in an `Either`:

`def processMany(inputs: Seq[Input]): Either[ErrorType, Seq[Output]] = ...`

`processMany` will call `processOne` for each input it has, however, I would like it to terminate the first time (if any) that `processOne` returns a `Left`, and return that `Left`, otherwise return a `Right` with a list of the outputs.

My question:  what is the best way to implement `processMany`?  Is it possible to accomplish this behavior using a `for` expression, or is it going to be necessary for me to iterate the list myself recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest with standard Scala, which doesn't evaluate more than is necessary, would probably be

```
def processMany(inputs: Seq[Input]): Either[ErrorType, Seq[Output]] = {
  Right(inputs.map{ x =>
    processOne(x) match {
      case Right(r) => r
      case Left(l) => return Left(l)
    }
  })
}
```

A fold would be more compact, but wouldn't short-circuit when it hit a left (it'd just keep carrying  it along while you iterated through the entire input).

Answer (score 5):

With [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) 7:

```
def processMany(inputs: Seq[Input]): Either[ErrorType, Seq[Output]] =
  inputs.toStream traverseU processOne
```

Converting `inputs` to a `Stream[Input]` takes advantage of the non-strict `traverse` implementation for `Stream`, i.e. gives you the short-circuiting behaviour you want.

By the way, you tagged this "monads", but traversal requires only an applicative functor (which, as it happens, is probably defined in terms of the monad for `Either`). For further reference, see the paper *[The Essence of the Iterator Pattern](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf)*, or, for a Scala-based interpretation, Eric Torreborre's [blog post](http://etorreborre.blogspot.de/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html) on the subject.

Comment: [Views](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) would work just as well as a stream, right? Using `.view` instead of `.toSteram`.

Comment: That would require a `Traverse[SeqView]` instance, which I don't think is available out of the box in scalaz.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've decided to just solve this using recursion, as I am reluctant to add a dependency to a library (Scalaz).

(Types and names in my application have been changed here in order to appear more generic)

```
def processMany(inputs: Seq[Input]): Either[ErrorType, Seq[Output]] = {
  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  @tailrec
  def traverse(acc: Vector[Output], inputs: List[Input]): Either[ErrorType, Seq[Output]]  = {
    inputs match {
      case Nil =>   Right(acc)
      case input :: more =>
          processOne(input) match {
            case Right(output) =>  traverse(acc :+ output, more)
            case Left(e) => Left(e)
          }
    }
  }

  traverse(Vector[Output](), inputs.toList)
}
```

Comment: While this will work, I don't quite understand why you prefer this over e.g. the solution I posted.  Yours is both substantially longer and substantially slower unless you are working with small lists which usually have errors.

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to pass the typechecker.  How does the Left propagate up?

Comment: My mistake; sorry about that.  I overlooked the "return" the first time.  Your answer works.